# How do I capture the value of the prop in the text field?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have a prop and currently am able to get the data of the prop, Am trying a way to capture the item of the prop when saving the form.

Is there a way where i can take the value and pass if in a hidden text-area and bind the data to the vmodel?

Any help I appreciate.

```
  <v-dialog v-model="dialog" persistent max-width="800">
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
      <v-btn dark v-on="on" color="primary" round> Make payment </v-btn>
    </template>

    <v-card>
      <v-card-title class="headline primary">
        <span class="white--text">Add a new Doctor Payment Record {{ queueId }}</span>
        
        <v-btn icon dark @click.native="dialog = false" absolute right>
          <v-icon>mdi-close</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-card-title>

      <v-card-text>
        <users-search
            :leave-selected="true"
            idOnly
            label="Select Doctor"
            @results="setDoctor"
        >
        </users-search>
    <div class="row px-3">
      <v-autocomplete
          class="px-3 col-sm-8"
          v-model="expense.bank"
          v-if="banks.data"
          :items="banks.data"
          outline
          chips
          label="Select bank"
          item-text="name"
          item-value="id"
      >
      </v-autocomplete>

      <v-text-field
          class="px-3 col-sm-8"
          outline
          flat
          v-model="expense.amount"
          type="number"
          @input="expense.percentage()"
          required
          label="Amount *"
          persistent-hint
      />
   

    </div>
        <v-text-field
            class="px-3"
            outline
            flat
            v-model="expense.total_paid"
            required
            label="amount paid"
            persistent-hint
        />
        <v-text-field
          class="px-3"
          outline
          flat
          :value="setQueue"
          v-model="expense.queueId"
          required
          :label=queueId
          persistent-hint
      /> 
        <v-alert :value="true" type="error" v-if="errors.any()">
          <div v-html="errors.display()"></div>
        </v-alert>

        <v-layout row wrap>
          <v-flex xs12>


            <v-btn
                color="success"
                :loading="saveLoader"
                @click="recordExpense()"
            >save</v-btn
            >
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
import NewUser from "@finance/libs/users/NewUser";
import {mapActions, mapGetters} from "vuex";

export default {
  props: [
    'queueId'  
  ],
  data: () => ({
    dialog: false,
    expense: new NewUser(),
    saveLoader: false,
  }),

  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      banks: "getBanks",
    }),

    balance: function () {
      return parseFloat(10);

    },
    submitted() {
      return this.expense.form.submitted;
    },

    contaminated() {
      return this.expense.form.errorDetected;
    },

    errors() {
      return this.expense.form.errors;
    },
  },

  watch: {
    submitted(v) {
      if (v) {
        this.saveLoader = false;
      }
    },

    contaminated() {
      this.saveLoader = false;
    },
  },

  methods: {
    ...mapActions({
      fetchBanks: "setBanks",
    }),
    setDoctor(user) {
      this.expense.doctor_id = user.id;
    },
    setQueue(){
      console.log(this.queueId);
      this.expense.queueId = this.queueId;
    },

    async recordExpense() {
      this.saveLoader = true;
      let response = await this.expense.saveExpense();
      this.saveLoader = false;

      if (response) {
        this.dialog = false;

        this.$emit("expenseCreated");
      }
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fetchBanks();
  }
};
</script>
```

The prop queueId i also want to store it along with the user information from the form.

Comment: You're probably looking for `<input type="hidden" :value="queueId">`. See [hidden input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden). You could use `v-model` on it - and you'd need a computed setter+getter for that - but you don't need to. That's because two-way binding is useless for a hidden input, since there's no user interaction.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one, it should work:

```
<template>
  <textarea v-model="hiddenValue" :style="{ display: 'none' }"></textarea>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: [ 'queueId' ],
  data() {
    return {
      hiddenValue: this.queueId
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

In case you will no need the prop to be modified, please bind the texarea value to the prop directly:

```
<textarea hidden v-model="queueId" :style="{ display: 'none' }></textarea>
```